# android camera2 setTorchMode too slow

Tags: android, performance, flashlight

I am using Camera2 to turn on the Flash Light on my Android phone with the following :

```
camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
```

But the thing is it's really slow (like half a second to open), compared to the iOS flashlight. I can't find any instantaneous flashlight, is it a hardware issue..?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's a hardware issue.

If the underlying hardware directly supports a enable-torch call at the HAL (hardware abstraction layer) interface, turning the flash on and off is very fast.

But if it doesn't, the Android OS has to actually open a camera device and turn on the flash via the full camera API. And unfortunately, powering on and off the camera is not a quick (or power-efficient) operation.

The needed HAL interfaces for this were added in Android 6.0 along with the setTorchMode API, but since the backwards compatibility code exists in the OS, not all manufacturers have added the necessary HAL implementation for fast flash control.

Comment: I understand. Well, thanks a lot for this accurate answer!